# Как заполнить массив alphaArray так, что бы до N-го элемента он заполнялся по одной формуле, а после – по другой?

Tags: массивы, ruby, циклы

Нужно заполнить массив alphaArray так, что бы до 140-го элемента он заполнялся по формуле `log(a*i+b)`, где `b = (Math.exp(1) - (Math.exp(alpha)))/(m-1)`,  `a = Math.exp(1)**(alpha)-b`
А после сто сорокового заполнялся единицами. Написал вот такой код:

```
arr = Array.new(200)
alpha=0.5
m=140
b = (Math.exp(1) - (Math.exp(alpha)))/(m-1)
a = Math.exp(1)**(alpha)-b
alphaArray = []
i=0
for i in m 
alphaArray.push Math.log(a*i+b)
i=i+1
end
for i in arr.length
alphaArray.push 1 
i=i+1
end
```

Но код не работает. Подскажите где ошибка? Пока новичок в руби, по это возникают трудности. И хотел бы узнать, может дадите ссылку почитать как обращаться к элементам двумерного массива и как с ними правильно работать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите:

1. Циклы: `for .. in ..` используется в случаях, когда надо итерироваться по перечисляемым объектам (массивам, хешам и подобному), в вашем случае вы пытаетесь итерироваться по числу, в результате видите то, что видите - сообщение об ошибке. Попробуйте итерироваться так:

   ```
   m.times do |i|
     #ваш код
   end
   ```

   Кроме того, `i=i+1` в цикле делать нужно, только если вы используете while.
2. Первая строка правильная, только поправьте название массива, чтобы соответствовало тому, который используется дальше, а `alphaArray = []` уберите. Еще в конструктор можно передавать вторым параметром значение элемента массива по умолчанию (в вашем случае 1), тогда второй цикл вам не нужен. И менять значение элемента можно не с помощью метода push, который добавляет новый элемент в конец массива, а присваивая элементу массива с индексом `i` нужное значение
3. Опционально в конструктор можно передавать блок, код в котором будет вызываться для каждого элемента создаваемого массива. С помощью блока можно создать и заполнить нужный массив из 200 элементов еще короче, 1 строкой:

   ```
   alphaArray = Array.new(200) {|i| (i <= m ? Math.log(a*i + b) : 1) }
   ```

Полезные ссылки:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays

Comment: Спасибо огромное!